# cakephp is passing action name as query, when the 'controllerA/action' is called from controllerB/actionB

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have problem in these two controllers 'Users' and 'Customers' and their models have relation of many to one.

in both controllers I have one function called assignToAccountManager()
when I am calling customers/assignToAccountManager from users/assignToAccountManager i am getting this error:

**Warning (512):** SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'assignToAccountManager' at line 1 [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 525]

Query: assignToAccountManager

this is my users/assignToAccountManager() function:

```
public function assignToAccountManager($userId=""){

        $userId = $userId;
        $userId = 1235;
        $this->User->id = $userId;
        $customerId = $this->User->field('customer_id');
        $this->User->Customer->id = $customerId;
        if($this->User->Customer->field('account_manager_id')){
            $this->User->Customer->assignToAccountManager($customerId);                                             
        }
        else{

        }
    }
```

and this is my assignToaccountManger function from customers controller

```
public function assignToAccountManager($customerId){
        if($customerId = ''){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $this->loadModel('AccountManager');
            $accountManagerId = array_rand($this->AccountManager->find('list', array(
                    'fields'=>array('id')
                )),1);

            $this->Customer->id = $customerId;
            $this->Customer->saveField('account_manager_id', (string)$accountManagerId);

        }
    }
```

Comment: according to my opinion, U should put "assignToAccountManager" in app_controller.then u can use this function in both controller easily.

Answer (score 0):

Having an action call another action on another controller is usually considered bad form.

The assignToAccountManager in your Customer controller should be relocated a model; the Customer model will probably work best, since this is the way your Users controller is accessing it.

So that the function in the Customer model doesn't have to do a loadModel, you should set up a relationship between the Customer and the AccountManager. Based on your code, Customer belongsTo AccountManager is the appropriate relationship.  Once done, the model code would be adjusted to:

```
public function assignToAccountManager($customerId){
    if($customerId = ''){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $accountManagerId = array_rand($this->AccountManager->find('list', array(
                'fields'=>array('id')
            )),1);

        $this->id = $customerId;
        $this->saveField('account_manager_id', $accountManagerId);

    }
}
```

You shouldn't need to cast $accountManagerId to a string, since all *_id fields should be int or bigint, just like the id field on the account_manager table.